# "Case" in the order-by statement

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I have the following linq statement:

```
IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> allTransactions 
    = TabTransaktions1.Union(TabTransaktions2)
                      .Where(trans => trans.TabVorgang != null).
                       .OrderBy(tran => tran.TabVorgang.Wirkdatum)
                      .OrderByDescending(trans2 => trans2.TabVorgang.ID);
```

But I want the second order by descending when only `trans2.TabVorgang.ID` equals to 0. So I need a "case" in "order by clause" for LinQ. A LinQ equivalent of something like this:

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalariedFlag
FROM HumanResources.Employee
ORDER BY CASE SalariedFlag WHEN 1 THEN BusinessEntityID END DESC
        ,CASE WHEN SalariedFlag = 0 THEN BusinessEntityID END;
GO
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: your questions seems to be very confusing. Can you provide sample data with the desired output you want ?

Comment: I want the data with the TabVorgang.ID = 0 to be at last. i dont want to touch the ordering otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SalariedFlag` is a `bool` (in SQL of type `bit`), the two ordering expressions are exclusively mutual. In other words, the main query can be separated into two disjunctive queries and the final result is the union of them:

```
IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> mainQuery
    = TabTransaktions1.Union(TabTransaktions2)
                      .Where(trans => trans.TabVorgang != null);

var queryOne  =  mainQuery.Where(p=>p.SalariedFlag ==1)
                       .OrderByDescending(tran => tran.BusinessEntityID );

var queryTwo  =  mainQuery.Where(p=>p.SalariedFlag ==0)
                       .OrderBy(tran => tran.BusinessEntityID);

var finalResult = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);
```

Comment: I was just about to do this. Thank you anway.

Comment: not to confuse anyone what i meant was this actually ; IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> mainQuery
= TabTransaktions1.Union(TabTransaktions2)
.Where(trans => trans.TabVorgang != null);
IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> queryOne = mainQuery.Where(p => p.TabVorgang.ID != 0)
.OrderBy(tran => tran.TabVorgang.Wirkdatum);
IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> queryTwo = mainQuery.Where(p => p.TabVorgang.ID == 0)
.OrderBy(tran => tran.TabVorgang.Wirkdatum).ThenByDescending(trans2 => trans2.TabVorgang.ID);
IEnumerable<TabTransaktion> allTransactions = queryOne.Union(queryTwo);